# Are sufficiently large key sizes enough to deter quantum attacks for symmetric key ciphers?

Tags: aes, symmetric, post-quantum-cryptography

Are sufficiently large key sizes enough to deter quantum attacks for symmetric key ciphers such as AES?

Comment: I did not find a direct duplicate; but this is [related](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3699/555), and the [top](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/21087/555) two [answers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/5755/555) cover it.

Comment: @fgrieu But I did find a direct dupe. It's missing the generic statement for other symmetric ciphers, but I guess pointing to a generic construct such as Grover's algorithm does the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Current understanding of quantum cryptanalysis suggests: **Generally, yes.**

Symmetric crypto tends not to have any mathematical structure that can be exploited by, *e.g.*, Shor's algorithm, so, absent specific quantum cryptanalysis of a specific primitive (which would be a remarkable publication about the specific primitive), the adversary is limited to the generic Grover's algorithm.

Grover's algorithm searches among $n$ possibilities for a preimage under some fixed function in $O(\sqrt{n})$ sequential qubit operations—for example, it should take about $2^{96}$ qubit operations to find $k$ among the $2^{192}$ possibilities given $f(k)$ where $f\colon k \mapsto \operatorname{AES-192}_k(8432715)$—so the conventional wisdom is that you just need to double your key sizes to attain the same security level against a quantum adversary as you had against a classical adversary.

Even better, [a recent estimate](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/811) with more careful attention to realism of cost models suggests that owing to Grover's poor parallelism in contrast to [classical brute force](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#bruteforce), it doesn't take much to thwart generic quantum attacks in more practical terms—if AES-128 is construed to provide 128-bit security against a classical adversary (which is debatable in the multi-target setting!), even AES-192 should provide 128-bit security against a quantum adversary, for example.